# df.index.map only for a certain series of data that we specified with the condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to tell the code to look inside the dataframe and only if their month number is equal to 8, do the search based on the terminal and define the penalty for them.

```
def calculate_under_60_purchase(two_month_average):
    if two_month_average <= 60:
        return 12000
    else:
        return 0


df_group_by_purchase = df.groupby('شماره ترمینال', as_index=False, dropna=False)['تعداد خرید'].sum()
df_group_by_purchase["میانگین خرید دو ماه"] = df_group_by_purchase['تعداد خرید'] / 2
df_group_by_purchase["purchase penalty"] = df_group_by_purchase["میانگین خرید دو ماه"].apply(calculate_under_60_purchase)

df_group_by_purchase.set_index("شماره ترمینال", inplace=True)
df.set_index("شماره ترمینال", inplace=True)

# I get an error when running this line
df.loc[(df["month number"] == 8), "purchase penalty"] = 
df.index.map(df_group_by_purchase["purchase penalty"])
df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

But I get this error when running:

```
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 2714 input values to the 
1378 output values where the mask is true
```

If you do not understand the names of the columns, it is because they are written in Persian language

I would be grateful if you telling me how I can do the map considering a specific condition <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.loc[(df["month number"] == 8), "purchase penalty"]` is filtered to include only months with month number 8, so it has less rows than the unfiltered array `df.index.map(df_group_by_purchase["purchase penalty"])`. This is essentially what the error message is saying, you are trying to assign an array with 2714 values into an array with 1378 values.
Something like this should work:

```
mask = (df["month number"] == 8)
df.loc[mask, "purchase penalty"] = 
df.index[mask].map(df_group_by_purchase["purchase penalty"])
```

This should be equivalent to the simpler option:

```
mask = (df["month number"] == 8)
df.loc[mask, "purchase penalty"] = df_group_by_purchase.loc[mask, "purchase penalty"])
```